# Update child component props values from parent state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that on a state change updates values (from a JSON file) of child components. I'm new to React.

The child component is a "card". The parent is a "game board", it fetches cards from a deck and place them in the player's hands. The child "card" component is to render the card (it also has a flipping animation when clicked), it gets its 'value' through its props. The "hand size" (number of cards to display) can also be changed from yet another parent, which I realize will produce the same problem, I haven't gone that far yet!

Parent 'Game.js':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Game.css';
import Card from '../../components/Card/Card.js';
import cardsdata from '../../data/cards-data.json';

class Game extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            gamemode: props.mode,
            handsize: parseInt(props.size),
            hand: [],
            deck: cardsdata.slice()
        };
        this.refreshHand = this.refreshHand.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshHand();
    }

    refreshHand() {
        // check if there is enough cards left in deck
        if (this.state.deck.length >= this.state.handsize) {
            // grab random cards to renew hand
            let newhand = Array(this.state.handsize).fill(null);
            let newdeck = this.state.deck.slice();
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.handsize; i++) {
                let rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * newdeck.length);
                newhand[i] = newdeck.splice(rng, 1)[0];
            }

            this.setState({
                hand: newhand,
                deck: newdeck
            });
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        let handview = this.state.hand.map((card, index) => {
            return (
                <Card card={card} key={index} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="Game-container">
                {handview}
                <button onClick={() => this.refreshHand()}>Refresh</button>
                <p>Cards left in deck: {this.state.deck.length}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Game;
```

The child 'Card.js':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Card.css';

class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isFlipped: false,
            wrapperclass: "card_wrapper",
            index: props.index,
            shine: props.card.shine,
            rough: props.card.rough
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this.state.isFlipped) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                isFlipped: false,
                wrapperclass: "card_wrapper anim_reverse"
            }));
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                isFlipped: true,
                wrapperclass: "card_wrapper anim_forward"
            }));
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState({
            index: newProps.index,
            shine: newProps.card.shine,
            rough: newProps.card.rough
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card_box" >
                <div className={this.state.wrapperclass} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <div className="card_face">
                        <span className="align-center">{this.state.rough}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card_face c_back">
                        <span className="align-center">{this.state.shine}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card;
```

Since I'm still very much learning all this, any additional feedback would be greatly appreciated.

I used "componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)" in the child component and it works but I've read this shouldn't be used anymore. What should I do instead?

Comment: I think I solved my problem, without using "componentWillReceiveProps". The keys I was using to instantiate the children components were always the same (default array keys). So it wasn't making the children unique when they are updated by the parent. I added an index for each "cards" in the JSON, and used that as keys. Now every time the "hand is refreshed" the <card> elements are updated because they have different keys.

I'm not sure if I'm clear in my solution... but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it.

The index used to render each children component was always the base array index (from 0 to whatever the "handsize" is).

I added an index in the JSON holding the cards values, so each value has a unique key.

So rendering the parent becomes:

```
render() {
    let handview = this.state.hand.map((card, index) => {
        return (
            <Card card={card} key={card.index} />
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="Game-container">
            {handview}
            <button onClick={() => this.refreshHand()}>Refresh</button>
            <p>Cards left in deck: {this.state.deck.length}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```